# Fine-Uploader-Select Files button does not display in IE

Tags: fine-uploader

In all other browsers, except IE, the Select Files button displays.  Also, when I debug on my machine, the button displays in IE. However, it does not display in IE, when running on the server.  Is there a bug? Here's my code:

```html
<div id="manual-fine-uploader" ></div>
<div id="triggerUpload">
    <input type="button" value="Upload" style="width:100px; cursor:pointer" /> 
</div>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             var manualuploader = new qq.FineUploader({
                 element: $('#manual-fine-uploader')[0],
                 request: {
                     endpoint: 'Letter/UploadFiles'
                 },
                 autoUpload: false,
                 text: {
                     uploadButton: '<input type="button" value="Select Files" class="qq-upload-button" />'

                 }
             });

             $('#triggerUpload').click(function () {
                 manualuploader.uploadStoredFiles();
             });
         });
    </script>
```

Comment: Interesting. You've checked the console to ensure that everything is getting loaded correctly (fineuploader.js and fineuploader.css), I assume?

This is a weird one to diagnose without more information. Is the upload succeeding?

Comment: Yes, the upload is succeeding.  I would think if there was a problem with the console, it would have affect other browsers, as well. Right?

Comment: I've tested in IE7 and IE8.  It was fine in IE9.  It appears that for some reason, the text in the button is transparent.  So, for example, in my form, the background color is blue.  The Upload Files button inherits that background color, instead of the color that I have in my css file.  I just ended up creating an image for the button.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should probably remove the "qq-upload-button" class from the input element you are using for the upload button text.  That class is used by Fine Uploader for selecting the container for the upload button.

If you are still seeing production-only issues, you will need to check your codebase to determine what CSS/HTML/javascript you are pushing specifically to production that may be causing any issues.